# ListView in VirtualMode not display ImageList image even when set in collection?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView in VirtualMode. The ListView has an ImageList in StateImageList with 4 images. When ever I'm building my ListViewItem collection, I am assigning image index of 1 too all my items as so:

```
lvItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Column0", "Column1" }, 1);
lvItemCol.Add(lvItem);
```

In my RetrieveVirtualItem event, I'm doing:

```
e.Item = lvItemCol[e.ItemIndex];
```

What can I do so that the appropriate image is displayed on my listview items in ListView? So far it just displays a blank space where the image would be.

Comment: Does it work better when not in virtualMode?

Comment: I was able to get it to display images now, by putting the ImageList in smallimagelist, but it is always at index 0. it won't change even if  i set the imageindex to 1 or 2 before adding the listviewitem to my collection.

Comment: You need to set the StateImageIndex separately. The constructor only lets you set the ImageIndex.